# como puedo modificar una linea de un archivo de texto y tenerlo guardado en forma de variable

Tags: c++, archivo, variables

tengo un archivo de texto de la siguiente forma:
21
IAIADAADAAADAIADAAADA
deseo guardar la segunda linea del texto, en una variable de la siguiente forma
**I;A;I;A;D;A;A;D;A;A;A;D;A;I;A;D;A;A;A;D;A;**
para ello tengo el siguiente código en el que puedo imprimirlo como quiero, pero no logro guardar la linea en una sola variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void lectura();

int main() {
lectura();

system("pause");
return 0;
}

void lectura(){
ifstream archivo_entrada("prueba5.txt");;
    string linea,codigo,aux;
    string caracter;

    int contador = 0;
    int max= 2;

    
    while(getline(archivo_entrada, linea)) {

            if(max == contador) {
                    cout << linea << endl;
            }

            contador++;
    }
    
   //codigo=linea;
   
   caracter=";";
   
   for(int i=0;i<linea.size();i++){
    cout<<linea[i]<<";";
    aux=linea[i];
   } 
   codigo=aux+caracter;
   cout<<endl;
   
   cout<<codigo<<endl;

}
```

¿que debo hacer para poder tener la linea de texto en una variable y que se encuentre modificada con las **;** entre las letras?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de inyectar los datos en el flujo de consola (`cout` → *`c`onsole `out`put*) inyéctalos en un flujo de texto:

```
std::string linea = "IAIADAADAAADAIADAAADA";
std::stringstream salida;

for (const char &caracter : linea)
    salida << caracter << ';';

std::cout << "Resultado: " << salida.str();
```

El flujo de texto está disponible mediante la cabecera `<sstream>`, el código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##VY3LCsIwEEXXzVcMEWy7UFynVSi46dY/GNJYAzEpeazEb4@J8UEhQ4YzZ@7wZdlxhXqOcSM1V2ES0EvjvBV4P5E/S0TqeUW@EpHawx2lblryIJXzE2NFByW1QDgCHYdxOA/5pRo/P@1WdskDh0pO2BFSXY2FhhvtPPAbWthytMi9sMBKckuqqujQ9/Cbpr7u6pzwTucm@MzoRbigPE6GAc2grO7T3abNthU@WA2HjjxjfAE):

> ```
> Resultado: I;A;I;A;D;A;A;D;A;A;A;D;A;I;A;D;A;A;A;D;A;
> ```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, no sabia nada acerca del stringstream